# Horizontal Scrolling With Grid in Tailwind

Tags: reactjs, typescript, frontend, tailwind-css

I've been trying to make content cards in a website and I want the content cards grid to be scrolled instead of putting it in another row. Is there any way to do this?

```
ssName="mt-2 text-lg text-gray-700" style={{ zIndex: 1, marginTop: 30, color:'white' }}>
            Recommendation
          </p>
        </div>
        <div
        className=" <----- here is the div that handles the grid
          pt-2
          grid
          sm:grid-cols-2
          md:grid-cols-3
          lg:grid-cols-4
          xl:grid-cols-5
          2xl:grid-cols-6
          gap-4
          relative
          z-0
          overflow-x-auto
          flex-wrap
        "
        >
          {listings.map((listing: any) => (
            <ListingCard currentUser={currentUser} key={listing.id} data={listing} />
          ))}
        </div>
</Container>
```

This is the code of the parent card:

```js
return (
    <div 
      onClick={() => router.push(`/listings/${data.id}`)} 
      className="col-span-1 cursor-pointer group"
    >
      <div className="flex flex-col gap-2 w-full">
        <div 
          className="
            aspect-square 
            w-full 
            relative 
            overflow-hidden 
            rounded-xl
          "
        >
          <Image
            fill
            className="
              object-cover 
              h-full 
              w-full 
              group-hover:scale-110 
              transition
            "
            src={data.imageSrc}
            alt="Listing"
          />
          <div className="
            absolute
            top-3
            right-3
          ">
            <HeartButton 
              listingId={data.id} 
              currentUser={currentUser}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="font-semibold text-lg" style={{color: "white"}}>
          {reservationDate || data.title}
        </div>
        <div className="font-light text-neutral-500">
        {location?.region}, {location?.label}
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-row items-center gap-1">
          <div className="font-semibold">
            Rp. {price}
          </div>
          {!reservation && (
            <div className="font-light">night</div>
          )}
        </div>
        {onAction && actionLabel && (
          <Button
            disabled={disabled}
            small
            label={actionLabel} 
            onClick={handleCancel}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
   );
}
```

This is the result of the above code. Lahendong should be scrolled instead of putting it in the new row

[image: this is the result of the above code. Lahendong should be scrolled instead of putting it in the new row]

I have tried to put overflow-x-auto but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider:

- Applying `grid-auto-flow: column` to specify that elements should be distributed in extra column tracks (instead of the default row tracks).
- Applying `grid-auto-columns` to specify sizing for the automatically-created column row tracks.
- Removing the `grid-template-columns` values.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<body class="bg-slate-900">
  <div class="relative z-0 grid auto-cols-[10rem] grid-flow-col gap-4 overflow-x-auto pt-2">
    <div class="group col-span-1 cursor-pointer">
      <div class="flex w-full flex-col gap-2">
        <div class="relative aspect-square w-full overflow-hidden rounded-xl">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000" class="h-full w-full object-cover transition group-hover:scale-110" />
          <div class="absolute right-3 top-3">
            <HeartButton>HeartButton</HeartButton>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-lg font-semibold" style="color: white">{reservationDate || data.title}</div>
        <div class="font-light text-neutral-500">{location?.region}, {location?.label}</div>
        <div class="flex flex-row items-center gap-1">
          <div class="font-semibold">Rp. {price}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group col-span-1 cursor-pointer">
      <div class="flex w-full flex-col gap-2">
        <div class="relative aspect-square w-full overflow-hidden rounded-xl">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?" class="h-full w-full object-cover transition group-hover:scale-110" />
          <div class="absolute right-3 top-3">
            <HeartButton>HeartButton</HeartButton>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-lg font-semibold" style="color: white">{reservationDate || data.title}</div>
        <div class="font-light text-neutral-500">{location?.region}, {location?.label}</div>
        <div class="flex flex-row items-center gap-1">
          <div class="font-semibold">Rp. {price}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group col-span-1 cursor-pointer">
      <div class="flex w-full flex-col gap-2">
        <div class="relative aspect-square w-full overflow-hidden rounded-xl">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?0" class="h-full w-full object-cover transition group-hover:scale-110" />
          <div class="absolute right-3 top-3">
            <HeartButton>HeartButton</HeartButton>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-lg font-semibold" style="color: white">{reservationDate || data.title}</div>
        <div class="font-light text-neutral-500">{location?.region}, {location?.label}</div>
        <div class="flex flex-row items-center gap-1">
          <div class="font-semibold">Rp. {price}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group col-span-1 cursor-pointer">
      <div class="flex w-full flex-col gap-2">
        <div class="relative aspect-square w-full overflow-hidden rounded-xl">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?1" class="h-full w-full object-cover transition group-hover:scale-110" />
          <div class="absolute right-3 top-3">
            <HeartButton>HeartButton</HeartButton>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-lg font-semibold" style="color: white">{reservationDate || data.title}</div>
        <div class="font-light text-neutral-500">{location?.region}, {location?.label}</div>
        <div class="flex flex-row items-center gap-1">
          <div class="font-semibold">Rp. {price}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group col-span-1 cursor-pointer">
      <div class="flex w-full flex-col gap-2">
        <div class="relative aspect-square w-full overflow-hidden rounded-xl">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?2" class="h-full w-full object-cover transition group-hover:scale-110" />
          <div class="absolute right-3 top-3">
            <HeartButton>HeartButton</HeartButton>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-lg font-semibold" style="color: white">{reservationDate || data.title}</div>
        <div class="font-light text-neutral-500">{location?.region}, {location?.label}</div>
        <div class="flex flex-row items-center gap-1">
          <div class="font-semibold">Rp. {price}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group col-span-1 cursor-pointer">
      <div class="flex w-full flex-col gap-2">
        <div class="relative aspect-square w-full overflow-hidden rounded-xl">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?3" class="h-full w-full object-cover transition group-hover:scale-110" />
          <div class="absolute right-3 top-3">
            <HeartButton>HeartButton</HeartButton>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-lg font-semibold" style="color: white">{reservationDate || data.title}</div>
        <div class="font-light text-neutral-500">{location?.region}, {location?.label}</div>
        <div class="flex flex-row items-center gap-1">
          <div class="font-semibold">Rp. {price}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group col-span-1 cursor-pointer">
      <div class="flex w-full flex-col gap-2">
        <div class="relative aspect-square w-full overflow-hidden rounded-xl">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?4" class="h-full w-full object-cover transition group-hover:scale-110" />
          <div class="absolute right-3 top-3">
            <HeartButton>HeartButton</HeartButton>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-lg font-semibold" style="color: white">{reservationDate || data.title}</div>
        <div class="font-light text-neutral-500">{location?.region}, {location?.label}</div>
        <div class="flex flex-row items-center gap-1">
          <div class="font-semibold">Rp. {price}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```